# Correct way to get an associated object in a Rails 4 controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is probably a duplicate question, because it seems exceptionally elementary, but I must not be searching the right way. As you'll see, I'm new to Rails.

In Rails 4 I have two objects: Text and Project. Text `belongs_to :project` and Project `has_many :texts`.

When creating a new Text the user must select a Project from a dropdown of existing Projects--they will never create a new Project through the Texts Controller.

So, I've whitelisted `:project' in`texts_controller.rb`:

```
def text_params

  params.require(:text).permit(:type, :sort_title, :date_created, :project,
  ...
```

but now the `create` method has to do:

```
def create
  @text = Text.new(text_params.except('project'))
  @text.project = Project.find(text_params['project'])
...
```

in order to avoid `Project(...) expected, got String(...)`. Obviously I could just rename the param, but my form code looks like this:

```
<p>Select Project</p>
<%= f.collection_select :project, Project.all, :pid, :display_label  %>
```

and I haven't been able to figure out how to change the parameter name there.

I could be completely wrong, and actually doing the right thing, but I really doubt it; it doesn't feel very idiomatic to Rails to me, i.e. I'm not actually passing a Project, just its `id`, and, albeit in a small way, I feel like I'm breaking the "Skinny Controller, Fat Model" mantra. There are probably other problems as well. What's the proper 'Rails way' to do this? TIA!

**Edit**
Maybe it's my test that's bad. This is the factory I'm using to test this:

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :text do |t| 
    t.project { FactoryGirl.create(:project) } # not sure if this is right...

    # TODO: creator and contributor, and then catch validation errors in tests
    t.abstract { Array.new(rand(0..2)) { Faker::Lorem.paragraph(rand(1..7)) } }
    t.alternative_title { Array.new(rand(0..5)) { Faker::Lorem.sentence(5,true,3) } }
    t.audience { Array.new(rand(0..2)) { Faker::Lorem.sentence(5,true,3) } }
    t.citation { Array.new(rand(0..2)) { Faker::Lorem.sentence(5,true,3) } }
    t.date_created { rand(900..2000) }
    t.description { Array.new(rand(0..10)) { Faker::Lorem.paragraph(1,true,3) } }
    t.extent { Array.new(rand(0..2)) { Faker::Lorem.sentence(5,true,3) } }
    t.has_part { Array.new(rand(0..20)) { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3,true,5) } }
    t.language { Array.new(rand(0..5)) { Faker::Lorem.sentence(1,false,3) } }
    t.provenance { Array.new(rand(0..2)) { Faker::Lorem.paragraph(rand(1..7)) } }
    t.publisher { Array.new(rand(0..2)) { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3,true,3) } }
    t.rights { Array.new(rand(0..4)) { Faker::Lorem.sentence(5,true,3) } }
    t.series { Array.new(rand(0..2)) { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3,true,5) } }
    t.sort_title { Faker::Lorem.sentence(2,true,5) }
    t.subject { Array.new(rand(0..7)) { Faker::Lorem.sentence(1,true,3) } }
    t.title { Array.new(rand(1..2)) { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3,true,5) } }
    t.toc { Array.new(rand(0..2)) { Faker::Lorem.sentence(5,true,3) } }
    t.type "Text"
  end

end
```

And all of the POST tests are failing: https://github.com/pulibrary/pul-store/blob/development/spec/controllers/texts_controller_spec.rb#L46-L82

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the Projects already exist and the user is just selecting them from the collection dropdown.

Change your strong params method to:

```
def text_params
  params.require(:text).permit(:type, :sort_title, :date_created, :project_id,
  ...
```

Then your collection select field name to:

```
<p>Select Project</p>
<%= f.collection_select :project_id, Project.all, :pid, :display_label  %>
```

Finally, change your controller action to:

```
def create
  @text = Text.new(text_params)
  ...
```

Since Text belongs_to project it will have a `project_id` attribute you can directly assign from the params and it will be able to pick up the association as soon as you assign it:

```
@text = Text.new project_id: 1
@text.project # => #<Project id: 1>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, the Projects already exist. That last bit of code you added is where I'm confused. Where do I do that? In the controller? What happens to the rest of the text_params?

Comment: The last bit of code was meant just as an explanation. The part above where I wrote "change your controller to:" is what you should be doing along with the previous code changes I listed. Still unclear?

Comment: Ah, OK. You're describing exactly what I was expecting to happen. Still no joy though. Thinking maybe my tests are what's bad. See the edit.

Comment: What error does it fail with? Looking at your factory and tests, you're passing in more attributes than are allowed from your strong params. Just a hunch though.

Comment: Nope, all those attributes are allowed...I just abbreviated what I pasted into SO (hence the '...'. I thought I had, but hadn't, whitelisted `project_id`, and that solved it. Thanks a lot!